# find the least positive residue of $1!+2!+3!+...+100!$ modulo each of the following integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the least positive residue of $1!+2!+3!+...+100!$ modulo each of the following integers:

a) $2$

b) $7$

c) $12$

d) $25$

and I am stuck on how to do this. I know that you have to set $n \geq 1$ for a) and state $n!$ is divisible by $1 = 1$ but I do not know where these numbers come from.

Comment: What do you mean.. residue?

Comment: Let's do $12$. Every factorial from $4!$ on is divisible by $12$. So we need the least positive residue of $1!+2!+3!$, This is $9$.

Comment: Likewise for every factorial from 10! on and 25.

Comment: How do we know that it every factorial from 4! on is divisible by 12? How can we find that number?

Comment: so this is what I have gotten from your explanation...would this suffice? :
"For any n >=4!, n! is divisible by 12 so n! congruent 4 (mod 12). Thus 1! +2!+...+100! congruent 4! congruent 9 (mod 12) ??

Comment: Note that $n!|(n+1)!$

Comment: $n! \equiv 0$ (mod 12) for $n\geq 4$. So $1!+2!+3!+4!+... \equiv 1+2+6 \equiv 9$ (mod 12).

Answer (score 2):

$$1!+2!+\dots 100!\\ \equiv 1! +2!+3\times 2!+ 4\times 3\times  2!...\\ \equiv 1!+0+3\times 0+ 4\times 3\times  0...\equiv 1!\pmod 2$$

Because $2!$ is congruent to $0$ $\pmod 2$. As André Nicolas pointed out in the comments, $4!\equiv 0\pmod {12}$ which means that $5!$ which is $5\times 4!$ is congruent to $0$ as well. See if you can generalize this strategy to other moduli as well.

**EDIT:** Lets do the $\pmod {12}$ example.

$$1!+2!+\dots 100!\\ \equiv 1! +\ldots+4!+5\times 4! + 6\times 5\times 4!+7\times 6\times 5\times 4!+...\\ \equiv 1! +\ldots+24+5\times 24 + 6\times 5\times 24+7\times 6\times 5\times 24+... \pmod {12}$$ Because $4!=24$. $24=12\times 2$ which is congruent to $0\times 2=0$ $\pmod{12}$. So... $$1! +\ldots+24+5\times 24 + 6\times 5\times 24+7\times 6\times 5\times 24+..\\ \equiv 1!+2!+3!+0+5\times 0+6\times 5\times 0\ldots\\ \equiv 1!+2!+3! \pmod{12}$$ and $1!=1,2!=2,3!=6$ so $1!+2!+3!=1+2+6=9$

Comment: Im not sure I understand how that gives us the answer of 9

Comment: @jbebe44 ok I will edit my question to incorporate the mod 12 example.