# Factorial number theory question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

What are the last three digits of the sum $1!+2!+3!+4！+.....2020! \;$?

I got $313$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that the last $3$ digits of $n!$ for $n\ge15$ are $000$, so it's the same as the last three digits of $1!+2!+3!+4!+\cdots+14!$

Comment: So this means I just have to work up to 15! ?

Comment: Is there a specific answer to this? so I can check mine, Thanks！

Comment: [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3834160/edit) your question to include your attempt

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314219/find-the-last-digit-of-the-sum-123-49 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997439/find-the-least-positive-residue-of-123-100-modulo-each-of-the-follow and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531634/what-is-the-remainder-when-12345-50-is-divided-by-5 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509183/find-the-remainder-when-123-49-is-divided-by-7

Comment: Quick computer confirmation:  Indeed $313$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

For $n\ge15$, $5^3$ and $2^3$ divide $n!$, so the last three digits of $n!$ are $000$.

$1!+2!=3$; $3!+4!=30$; $5!+6!+7!+8!$ ends with $120+720+040+320\equiv200$;

$9!+10!+11!+12!$ ends with $880+800+800+600\equiv080$;

and $13!+14!$ ends with $800+200\equiv000$.

Therefore, the answer is $233+080=313$.